# No matching route found for RedirectToRoute

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute", "{Name}", "~/Default.aspx");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Listing", "{keyword}/{city}/{area}", "~/Listing.aspx");

    }
```

at the above code i have written two route first is "StoreRout" that is working fine
the second one "Listing" route that is not working
now my url is 
http://www.sitename.com/Listing.aspx?keyword=Media&City=Pune&area=camp

i am trying to url should be like  http://www.sitename.com/Media/Pune/camp
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate URL for second route is:

http://www.sitename.com/Listing/Media/Pune/camp